# Speeding up persist/save in Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a backend application in Spring/Java/Hibernate/Java/MySQL and I am using SessionFactory. I have a table/entity class with multiple parent-child relationships, I call parentDao.persist(object) to save, the operation takes a long time to complete, the object contains multiple child objects also, so parent/child is persisted on that call.

My table/entity is:

EventEntity

```
private Integer id;
private String entityId;
private String eventTitle;
private UserEntity organizer;
private BusinessEntity business;
private LocationEntity location;
//child objects
private List<EventsUserEntity> eventsUsers;
private List<FilterMappingEntity> filterMapping;
private List<EventMediaMapEntity> mediaMaps;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="event",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE},orphanRemoval=true)
public List<EventMediaMapEntity> getMediaMaps() {
return mediaMaps;}
@OneToMany(mappedBy="event",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
public List<FilterMappingEntity> getFilterMapping() {
return filterMapping;}
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public List<EventsUserEntity> getEventsUsers() {
return eventsUsers;
}
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public UserEntity getOrganizer() {
return organizer;
}
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public LocationEntity getLocation() {
return location;
}
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public BusinessEntity getBusiness() {
return business;
}
```

The child classes are populated during the service call and persisted by parent `DAO`. And all other foreign key objects are persistence object(i.e.objects retrieved from db) except `Location` object which is persisted along with `Event` object.
But when I persist `Event` entity, its takes a long time sometimes about 1min.
Please suggest me about speeding up the persisting operation.

Comment: That is most probably not caused by the persist operation itself. Check if you have database connection problems, or network issues, or locks in the database. Or maybe you chose a horribly slow ID generation algorithm. Enable SQL logging to know what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I enabled SQL logging too, it makes too much `select` queries before `insert` statement. How to avoid this ? ID generation is implemented via @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO). I tried this in local, so we can assume no network issues.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried this in local, so we can assume no network issues. And in database tx_isolation is set to `REPEATABLE-READ`.